# How to update the content when is deleted

Tags: reactjs

I simply can't get this thing working for me. I have an item that is being deleted on a backend side but it is not rendering immediately on a front. You need to refresh the whole page to make it work. I saw similar questions asked here, but I couldn't make it work on my example.

So here in my component I'm getting the data from backend:

```
const AdminMessages = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:5000/contact/message/`
        );
        setData(response.data);
        setError(null);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err.message);
        setData(null);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    getData();
  }, []);

return (
{data.map((item) => (
<h3 className="bold-text">{item.title}</h3>
                <div
                  name="trash-outline"
                  id="approve-icon"
                  onClick={() => dispatch(deleteContactMessage(item._id))}
                ></div>
        ))}
    )
  );
};
```

And here is my controller for delete:

```
export const deleteContactMessage = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id))
    return res.status(404).send("No post with that id");

  await ContactMessage.findByIdAndRemove(id);

  res.json({ message: "Post deleted successfully" });
};
```

Comment: Do you mean that you're expecting `deleteContactMessage(item._id)` to update the state of `data`?  Where is the code which does that?  If you're expecting `data` to be updated after this "delete" operation then something would need to update it, either directly or by re-fetching the new state of the data from the server.  Otherwise, yes, you'd need to refresh the page to see that update.

Comment: How can I update it directly?

Comment: By calling `setData()` and passing it the new updated state.  Exactly like you already do when fetching the values.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I cannot figure that out

Comment: Well, what is `dispatch(deleteContactMessage(item._id))` doing?  The "dispatch" part implies you may be using Redux or some other application-level state management?  If so then perhaps you want to move your component-level `data` state to that same state management and update it as part of that operation.  If you're not using a state management system then where is that delete operation defined and what does it do?  Should it be defined within the component?  Overall, manage state consistently.  The state itself and the operations which affect it should be parallel.